# Why when I click on the images does nothing happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery so hopefully this isn't two dumb of a question but I have looked around.

I have a simple todo list shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/letsGoHawks/fGdke/17/):   I am curious as to why when I click the images shown (after adding an item) the functions do nothing.

The following are the two methods of concern...I'm pretty sure they are not being called. I'm unsure why:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var reply = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this todo item?");
    if(reply === true) {
        $(this).closest('.item').remove();
    } 
});

$('.edit').on('click', function(event) { 
    $(this).closest('.item').slideDown('fast');
});
```

Comment: Because you have more objects of the same class.

Comment: Your `.on()` methods are invoked before you've created the elements. You can only bind handlers to elements that exist. To solve this you can use *event delegation*. This means that you bind the handlers to some ancestor, like your `#list` element, and then run your code when the proper nested element is clicked. jQuery's means of determining what was clicked uses CSS selectors. To find out how to use them, read the docs for `.on()`. Otherwise, you could just bind the handlers directly as you create the new elements.

Comment: Long time don't see this kind of question...

Comment: @roasted is that a good thing or a bad thing? Am I getting down-voted for not knowing something? Little ridiculous to me ... kind of the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use event delegation as follows:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.delete', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var reply = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this todo item?");
    if(reply === true) {
        $(this).closest('.item').remove();
    } 
});

$('#list').on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('.item').slideDown('fast');
});
```

Another, and more efficient, option would be to define your click handlers and then assign them to the elements after creating them:

```
var onDeleteButtonClicked = function(event) {
    //delete code from above.
};

var onEditButtonClicked = function(event) {
    //edit code from above.
};

function addTo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var toAdd = $('#addition').val();

    if(toAdd.length > 0) {
        var listItem = $('<li class="item">' + toAdd + '</li>');
        var img = $('<img class="delete" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/uidesignicons/delete.png">')
            .click(onDeleteButtonClicked); //Assign your delete click handler here.
        var img1 = $('<img width="4%" class="edit" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeapplication/png/24x24/Modify.png">')
            .click(onEditButtonClicked); //Assign your edit click handler here.
        listItem.append(img);
        listItem.append(img1);
        $('#list').append(listItem);
        $('#addition').val("")
    } else {
        alert("Cannot add empty list item!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What bout img.bind(...); ?

Comment: You don't "need" event delegation, but it is one option. Maybe you should explain to OP how this works.

Comment: @CrazyTrain True. He could assign the click event handler as the elements are created as well.

Comment: I understand what this is doing, thanks. I guess i thought that is what I was doing when I put everything inside of $(document).ready(function(){  <<HERE>>  });

Comment: @nickbonnet That would only run once when the document was fully loaded, and then not again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#container').on('click','.delete' ,function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var reply = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this todo item?");
    if(reply === true) {
        $(this).closest('.item').remove();
    }

});
```